# How do I Insert a Local String Variable into a TextWriter Writeline Method without it causing a line break?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, edi

I am attempting to insert a parsed XML element into the middle of a TextWriter WriteLine without it causing a line break where the variable is added, but am having no success. The purpose of the program is to transform an XML file into a .txt file in X12 850 EDI format, and I need to preserve the lines as dictated by the WriteLine methods. I am not certain this is the most efficient way to make the translation, as I am only one week into my C# career, but my other attempts using xslt files have proven inefficient. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code for my translator.

```
class Class1
{


    public static void Main()
    {

        StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();

        String xmlString = ("3.xml");

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(xmlString)))
        {
            reader.ReadToFollowing("Name");
            name.AppendLine(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test5.txt"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*daisywebstore  *12*5016361200     *11213*1022*U*00400*000001649*0*P*>~");
            sw.WriteLine("GS*PO*9254291001*5016361200*20111213*1022*1649*X*004010~");
            sw.WriteLine("ST*850*0001~");
            sw.WriteLine("BEG*00*SA*08272225944**20111213~");
            sw.WriteLine("REF*DP*089~");
            sw.WriteLine("DTM*002*20120104~");
            sw.WriteLine("N1*ST*" + name + "~");
            sw.WriteLine("N3*1400 S MC CARREN BLVD~");
            sw.WriteLine("SN4*SPARKS*NV*894316301~");
            sw.WriteLine("N1*RE**92*00103653341~");
            sw.WriteLine("PO1*1*6*EA*33.28*TE*IN*081643211*UP*30039256056937~");
            sw.WriteLine("PID*F****CO2 BB PISTOL     $ 5693~");
            sw.WriteLine("PO4*3*1*EA~");
            sw.WriteLine("CTT*1~");
            sw.WriteLine("AMT*1*199.68~");
            sw.WriteLine("SE*16*0001~");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing

```
name.AppendLine(reader.ReadElementContentAsString())
```

Which you shouldexpect to add a new line.  Maybe try just

```
name.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString())
```

instead?

EDIT:
Though it seems to be unnecessary for name to be a stringbuilder at all.  Maybe just make it a string?

In which case you could just do

```
name = reader.ReadElementContentAsString()
```

Comment: You were correct. Removing line from the Append method corrected the issue. I could not see the forest for the trees. I realize my coding may be a bit verbose, and I trying to do what I want to do as efficiently as possible, so I will try removing the StringBuilder as well. Thanks for the breakthrough.

Comment: My pleasure - and remember to mark the correct answer!  Good luck!